# Loop through JSON array - Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a `geneData.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
    "geneSearchBy": ["Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4"]
}
```

I want to read in and loop each value in the `geneSearchBy` array.

I tried this:

```
import geneData from '../geneData.json'

for(var item in geneData.geneSearchBy)
{
//do something
}
```

But that is not working, it is reading in an index value (0..etc)

Any ideas?

Comment: `for (var item of geneData.geneSearchBy) `. `of`, not `in`.

Comment: `for...in` is for objects not arrays